# Swift memory rebound of a struct

Tags: ios, swift, macos, memory

I a have a module, let’s call it `MySDK` that in a function returns an instance of `Any`. This SDK is consumed in a project of mine.

```
let theHatedAnyObject = MySDK().someAPI()
```

I know for sure that this instance is of a specific type of a dependency (`Dependency`) that it is also used in my project.

I'm trying to cast to that type, using an `as!` but it crashes, thus I'm trying to get a pointer from that struct and knowing the memory layout of that type trying to bind it from `Any` to that specific type.

I also tried to copy the memory but I get a crash.

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1344e229
```

First attempt:

```swift
import Depencency
import MySDK
let theHatedAnyObject = MySDK().someAPI() // It's Any but the real type used in SDK is DependencyStruct exposed my Dependency
let stride = MemoryLayout<DependencyStruct>.stride
let alignment = MemoryLayout<DependencyStruct>.alignment
let byteCount = MemoryLayout<DependencyStruct>.size

let _ = withUnsafeBytes(of: &theHatedAnyObject) { bytes in
    bytes.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: DependencyStruct.self, capacity: byteCount) { pointer in
        let value = pointer.pointee // Crash here
    }
}
```

Second attempt using `memcpy`:

```swift
import Dependency
import MySDK
let theHatedAnyObject = MySDK().someAPI() // It's Any but the real type used in SDK is DependencyStruct exposed my Dependency

let rawPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: byteCount, alignment: alignment)
let pointer = rawPointer.bindMemory(to: DependencyStruct.self, capacity: 1)
let _ = withUnsafeBytes(of: &theHatedAnyObject) { bytes in
  memcpy(pointer, bytes.baseAddress, byteCount)
  let value = pointer.pointee // Crash here
}
```

For the moment let's leave the `deallocation` aside.

The answer is. Is there any way to cast an object coming from another module from `Any` to a specific type knowing for sure the type and the memory layout of that specific object?

Comment: "but of course it crashes" Why "of course"? If you cast down to the type of thing that it really is, why should it crash?

Comment: Feels like the question to ask is 'why does the cast crash' as there's no reason why it should, rather than trying to hack around it by accessing memory directly.

Comment: Perhaps the `theHatedAnyObject` actually is something else, that just happen to have the same memory layout as `EmbraceBuffer`? If it were actually `EmbraceBuffer`, the cast should not fail. Please show `type(of: theHatedAnyObject)`, and the way you are casting it.

Comment: @Sweeper sorry the correct layout is ‘DependencyStruct‘ and yes ‘Any’ is of the same type of ‘ DependencyStruct’. I know for sure also because printing ‘theHatedAnyObject’ shows up the same properties of ‘DependencyStruct‘

Comment: "The same properties" is not the same thing as "the same type" in Swift. Do you have a stronger reason you believe the two are the same type?

Comment: @matt I said for sure because the Any object would be of inner type Module. DependencyStruct while the one i want to cast would be of type MyApp. DependencyStruct because I guess they would be namespaced by swift.

Comment: @RobNapier yes I’m the one who wrote the module that exposes the object as Any (and I can’t do differently due to a bug in swift compiler, there is a rdar open as Apple suggested me to do).

Comment: "the Any object would be of inner type Module. DependencyStruct while the one i want to cast would be of type MyApp. DependencyStruct" Well there you go. Those are two different types. How about simply writing a conversion function that converts one from the other?

Comment: Just to be clear, is the `theHatedAnyObject` of type `Any`? I.e. `let theHatedAnyObject = Depencency.someAPI()`? In that case, your issue that `theHatedAnyObject` is an existential container, and not an instance of `DependencyStruct`. It either contains the fields of a `DependencyStruct` inline, or points to a heap-allocated `DependencyStruct`, depending on the size of that type. Reverse engineering that would be a bit tricky, and very brittle.

Comment: @Alexander `theHatedAnyObject` is of type `Any` and exposed by an external SDK, more like `MySDK.someAPI() `. I know that the type of this object is `DependencyStruct ` because I use the `Dependency` also in `MySDK`.
In my project I would like to cast that `Any` to `DependencyStruct `. Casting doesn't work, I'm trying with memory rebound but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alexander I see as a container is just a wrapper around the original object, but I cannot explain why in the project of the SDK I have a unit test that make this cast possible. In the unit test the `MySDK` is imported as a separate module and the method used is the same `MySDK.someAPI()` why here is it working?

Comment: ok, I have a bunch of thoughts about this. 1) You probably already know this, but if `MySDK` decided to return it as an `Any`, they're probably trying to achieve some kind of abstraction. Do you have a good reason to circumvent that? Are there any other alternative approaches that remove the need for that? 2) "Casting doesn't work" When you check in the debugger, what's the runtime type of `theHatedAnyObject`? If it really is a `DependencyStruct`, then casting it to `DependencyStruct` should work (though it'll obviously be brittle) 3) In any case, if casting doesn't work, manually rebinding...

Comment: ...memory won't save you either, because if you don't know the type of the object you're expecting, then you probably don't know its layout, either. And if you did know the type, you could just have casted normally and not need to fiddle with the memory. 4) As I suggested earlier, rebinding the memory of an `Any` object (or any other existential container, really) would be pretty hard.

Comment: @Alexander thank you they are super enlightening suggestions